# Is there a word for not being sympathetic to a position, but also not being ardent towards it?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, antonyms

Is there a word for something like, "moderate opposition?"

Context: A friend and I are trying to find or create a phrase for someone who isn't an anti-theistic militant atheist, but also isn't an apologist for theism.

Comment: I happen to like "apatheist" but it may be too specialized for your use case.

Comment: "agnostic" won't work?

Comment: I always tell clergymen that although I'm an atheist, I'm not an *evangelical atheist*. (Generally gets a laugh, but your mileage may vary.)

Comment: I think you do not understand what "ardent" means.

Answer (score 1):

**wishy-washy**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wishy-washy)

> Informal
>
> a. Irresolute or indecisive:

Use the adjective wishy-washy to describe something that's ineffective or that wavers back and forth without a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

**Ambivalent** seems to fit your requirement. It's not a religion-specific word, but so much the better for that; it's important to get as much mileage out of every word as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A *fence-sitter* or to be *on the fence* perhaps.
Disinterested ( not 'uninterested', I know the difference)

Comment: Going back in time, *mugwump*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying, the person you're describing is a [**dispassionate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispassionate) atheist.

You cannot truly call this person neutral or ambivalent.  They have an opinion, they just *lack the ardor of a zealot on the subject*.  They're not burdened with strong emotions on the subject and therefore are able to have calm rational discussions about it.

In this case, they're an atheist who is willing to listen to the ideas of theists without starting a fight.  Their own opinion is unlikely to be swayed, but, they don't seek to change the opinion of the theists, either.